# AWS Canary in CloudWatch not reporting back to the service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-vpc

I am trying to run the blueprint for a standard heartbeat monitor against a web application and I keep seeing the error "Task timed out after 60.06 seconds" appear. I have a VPC with a private subnet for the Canary to run. I also have two endpoints associated with this VPC for metrics and synthetics. When I review the details in CloudWatch I see that the URL I am running the check against is requested and a response 200 is returned which is what I expected. I see the below which leads me to believe that the issue is that the Canary cannot send the data back to CloudWatch? Any assistance would be appreciated.

INFO Publishing result and duration CloudWatch metrics with timestamp: Tue Jan 12 2021 17:51:51 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) for canaryName: MyTestBird stepName: null result: PASSED startDateTimeInUTC: Tue Jan 12 2021 17:52:52 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) endDateTimeInUTC: Tue Jan 12 2021 17:53:07 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)

END RequestId: ca55f3c8-df84-41e5-9495-XXXX

REPORT RequestId: ca55f3c8-df84-41e5-9495-XXX Duration: 60060.45 ms Billed Duration: 60000 ms Memory Size: 1000 MB Max Memory Used: 190 MB

2021-01-12T17:53:51.778Z ca55f3c8-df84-41e5-9495-XXXX **Task timed out after 60.06 seconds**

Answer (score 0):

I too got a similar error, found this AWS solutions/guide.

**Possible causes:**

- If there's no access to Amazon S3,
- If a response from your monitored endpoint exceeds the timeout period configured
- If a security group, network access control list, or routing table doesn't allow access to the canary's endpoint

**Fix:**

- Confirm that the security group attached to the canary
  Allows outbound traffic to port 443 - 0.0.0.0/0 for Destination.
- Make sure that the ACL in the canary subnet allows inbound and outbound access

Go through this link for a detailed explanation - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-fix-failing-canary-in-vpc/